# C# Add Timestamp to PKCS#7 CMS Digital Signature problem

Tags: c#, timestamp, digital-signature, pkcs#7

This question is the continuation of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829810/c-sharp-add-timestamp-to-pkcs7-cms-digital-signature/59883865#59883865). I also try to communicate with a 3rd party AS2 server. I use the same code as the author of that post. This code (the corrected version) is:

```
private byte[] Sign(byte[] content)
{
    CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(_cert);
    cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));

    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(content));
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, true);

    return signedCms.Encode();
}
```

But I get the following error back from the server:

> Unable to verify content integrity: Message digest mismatch in
> signature.

in spite of `signedCms.CheckSignature(false);` doesn't throw an exception.

Where should I search the reason of this error?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the project type  to .net 5
by using project properties (right click on project -> properties) -> application and changed target framework from .net core 3.0 to .net 5.0 i hope it will help anybody